# User is not a constructor error - mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an error and after a few hours of trying, I can't figure out what's wrong.

I am trying to make a post request and get the error 'User is not a s´constructor'

**user.js:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')



const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {type:String, required:true},
    password :  {type:String, required:true}
    })


const us = mongoose.model('UserSchema', userSchema);
module.exports = {us}
```

**server.js:**

Import:

```
const  User = require ('./models/user')
```

POST method:

```
app.post('/save', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    const newUser =  new User({
        name : req.body.name,
        password : req.body.password
    }, { collection: 'Users' });
       
       newUser.save(function(err, data){
           if(err){
               console.log(error);
           }
           else{
               res.send("Data inserted");
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: try using `User.us`, because you are exporting it in object's `us` key

Comment: @turivishal I tried it but then my socket hangs up...